# Can't see my website after setting up CNAME pointing to Github Pages site

Tags: dns, website, domain, cname

I have made a new website (`www.codemuch.tech`) using get.tech as a domain name provider. I made a `CNAME` record that pointed `blog.codemuch.tech` to my Github Pages site, `ex0dus-0x.github.io`. However, when I attempt to visit that site, I do not get see my website. When I do it through my phone, I get redirected to `localhost`. When other people outside of my network visit the site, or when I access it through Tor, the site works and everything is displayed. What seems to be the problem and how can I fix this?

**Edit**: I've also tried setting two `A` records that pointed to Github's server, as directed [here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain/). Ran the site through Tor. Works, but when accessing on my network regularly, it doesn't work.

Comment: When you are testing from your machine and from your phone, is it the same network?  Sounds like you have a local DNS server that is pointing blog.codemuch.tech somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, I am on the same network. I do not have any recollection of actually setting up a DNS server that points my site elsewhere, and I just got the domain today.

Comment: Ah, ok.  So if you ping it from your network, vs externally, does it resolve to the same address?  It might be that you tried to resolve it before it was created, and you have a "fail" cached.

Comment: `--- PING github.map.fastly.net (151.101.84.133) 56(84) bytes of data. --- 64 bytes from 151.101.84.133: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=24.0 ms 64 bytes from 151.101.84.133: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=24.0 ms 64 bytes from 151.101.84.133: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=24.0 ms 64 bytes from 151.101.84.133: icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=24.0 ms`

Comment: This was the response I received. It appears to be from GitHub. I am doing this from my phone actually, which is currently on the same network

Comment: Yeah that looks right.   Perhaps your ISP has a proxy?

Comment: I do not believe so. I will reset my router and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by resetting my router. It seemed that my DNS may have cached a prior error when I visited my website **BEFORE** I created the subdomain. A router reset fixed everything.